# How to fix compiling problems with .css file

Tags: css, angular, debugging, sass

I'm currently following a tutorial that uses .scss but have decided to use .css instead. While I was following the tutorial I tried writing into the .css file but I ran into some compilation issues.

I'm not as familiar with .css so it was hard for me to fix them. I wasn't sure if the problem was with some of the syntax being exclusive to scss. The problem mainly lies in property-list-item.component.css and Property-list.component.css.

https://github.com/zhadjah9559/Wholesale-cli.git

Errors:

> ERROR in ./src/app/property/Property-list-item/property-list-item.component.css
>
> Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve 'variables' in 'C:\Users\zach\College\Spring 2019\Senior Proj\Wholesale-cli\src\app\property\Property-list-item'
>
> at doResolve (C:\Users\zach\College\Spring 2019\Senior Proj\Wholesale-cli\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:180:19)

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4DP5.png)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5o5G.png)

Also, does anyone know how to uninstall an extension? I believe i may be having a problem with one of the css formatter extensions i used in visual code.

UPDATE

```
@import 'variables';
a 6:hover,
a 6:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bsp-card {
    border: none;
}

.bsp-card .card-block {
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.bsp-card .card-subtitle {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #16861a;
}

.bsp-card .card-title {
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 3px 0;
}

.bsp-card .card-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you have?

Comment: You can't use SCSS syntax in CSS.

Comment: Your styling structure is `scss` way and your files are `.css` you either need to break it's into css structure or you need to install scss and rename your file to `.scss`.

Comment: Since you @import variables it's definitely scss way try installing scss and rename your files to .scss or you can create a new project with scss as default preprocessor running command like `ng new Your-Project --style scss` that's creates a cli app with scss preprocessor and files by default

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a new project you need to select CSS on generation like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file is trying to import a variables scss file that doesn't exist.

@import 'variables';

Remove that, but make sure there's no references to variables inside the css file.